# how to round to decimal point in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i need to round off up-to 2 decimal,currently i getting 12% but the actual discount is 11.76

my code as follow

```
$perc=0;
        if($value->IsOfferItem){
          $perc=round(100-(($value->SellingPrice/$value->ActualPrice)*100));
        }
```

Comment: [round()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) has a second parameter `int $precision = 0`. How is this related to html,css (or mysql)?

Comment: kerbh0lz am new into stack overflow and programming can you write the code

Comment: There are examples on the page I linked ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example

```
$table->decimal('amount', 5, 2);
```

In above example first parameter is the field name. Second, parameter is the total length. Third, parameter is the float value.

the table field, for example in mysql must contain decimal (10.2), example:

```
amount dcecimal(10,2) not null
```

The 2 indicates decimal places.

The 10 indicates the maximum numerical quantity before the comma.

Comment: I believe you didn't make this corretct table